# What is the difference between Primary and Satellite locations with anomalies?

Tags: ingress

In Ingress at events like `#Magnus13` and `Recursion` you have different cities appointed during an anomaly.

Now this time I saw this list at Decode Ingress:

> **Through Decoding Processes the exact dates and locations were determined**
>
> - Feb 15 – Miami – Primary, Columbus – Satellite,  Louisville - Satellite
> - February 22 – Bangalore -Primary, New Delhi - Satellite, Hyderabad - Satellite
> - March 1 – Nashville – Primary, Mobile - Satellite , Little Rock - Satellite
> - March 8 – Austin – Primary. Mexico City - Satellite, St. Louis – Satellite
> - March 15 – Nice - Zagreb – Primary, Nice - Satellite, Cagliari  - Satellite
> - March 22 – Boulder, Co – Primary,  Boise - Satellite,  Provo - Satellite
> - March  29 - Berlin  - Primary, Los Angeles – Primary, Nantes  - Satellite, Brussels - Satellite

There are `Primary` and `Satellite` locations. What is exactly the difference between these two?

Comment: In the past, The real difference that I have noticed is the amount of Ingress staff on premise, and thus the amount of swag given out.

Answer (score 3):

As discussed in the references for the question [What are the rules and circumstances in #recursion for artifact movement?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/161711/what-are-the-rules-and-circumstances-in-recursion-for-artifact-movement), one difference is that the target portal for the artifact movement opportunity which follows the recursion event is in the primary city.