# What are the rules and circumstances in #recursion for artifact movement?

Tags: ingress

In the #Recursion anomaly, following each weekend event there is a period of time in which artifacts can be moved around, as summarized on the [Ingress Report EP46 (transcript)](https://plus.google.com/u/0/117291070802201138527/posts/4Tyr5K6vDyh)

I've also heard that there are rules around the minimum level of a portal that holds an artifact.

What is the full set of rules, or at least sitreps for the various artifact movements to date (like [FRANCE SITREP FOR ARTIFACTS 7 AND 8  #Recursion    Shards, we deliver.  Ingress Resistance Paris - France - Google+](https://plus.google.com/116962023613219736912/posts))

Update: more questions:

Do artifacts only move at the top of the hour or 30 minutes after the hour?

If there are multiple eligible links out from a portal that has an artifact, where does it move to?

What does "locking" of artifacts mean?

Answer (score 2):

The rules change from week to week, and sometimes during play, it seems.

The rules for the Las Vegas event are at [IQTech Research - Google+ - #DICE2014   #RECURSION](https://plus.google.com/u/0/108020987035258478791/posts/VSPAFaxYuu4)

Rules for the [final LA/Berlin event](https://plus.google.com/+Ingress/posts/cWpvfdNMits)

Example of rule changes for L7+ portals needed for artifacts:
[Ingress post on G+: Breaking lab analysis](https://plus.google.com/app/basic/stream/z13ac5obasu3edrgb04cepti1mqucru4ujs)

Some updates are at [Ingress - Google+ - #RECURSION XM ARTIFACT STATUS](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+Ingress/posts/LVU5GGpcxXU)